# Why is my CSS different on deployed Mezzanine versus local?

Tags: django, mezzanine

My CSS on my production deployment different than my local run.

## Diff between /static/css/mezzanine.css on local and PROD

```
/* Navigation */
2       - body {padding-top:45px;}
3       - @media (max-width:979px){
4       -     body {padding-top:0;} .brand {padding-right:20px !important;}}
2   + @media (max-width:979px){.brand {padding-right:20px !important;}}
5   3     .navbar {z-index:500;}
6       - .navbar .btn {margin:7px 0;}
7   4     .navbar-inner {border-radius:0;}
8       - .navbar-search * {margin:0 2px !important;}
9       - .navbar-search .search-query {width:120px; border-radius:3px}
5   + .navbar-search {margin-left:10px; margin-top:4px;}
6   + .navbar-search * {border-radius:4px !important; margin:0 2px !important;}
10  7     .navbar-search select {width:auto;}
11      - .navbar-text {float:left; font-size:12px; font-style:italic; margin:0; opacity:.6;}
8   + .navbar-search .btn {margin-top:1px !important; margin-left:4px !important;}
9   + .tagline {float:left; font-size:12px; font-style:italic; margin:9px 5px 0 -4px; color:#fff; opacity:.5;}
12  10    .breadcrumb {margin:20px 0 25px 0;}
13  11    .breadcrumb .divider {margin:0 5px;}
14  12    .breadcrumb strong {color:#333;}
15  13    ul.nav li.dropdown:hover ul.dropdown-menu {display:block;}    
16  14    .pull-right .dropdown-menu a {text-align:right;}
17  15    .tree {padding:8px;}
18  16    .tree li {margin:3px 0;}
19  17    footer {background:rgba(220,220,220, 0.1); padding:30px 0; text-    align:center; margin-top:40px;}
20  18    footer .container {text-align:left; display:inline-block; width:auto;}
21  19    footer li {float:left; list-style-type:none;}
22  20    footer li li {float:none; clear:both; width:120px; padding:10px 0; margin-right:30px;}
23  21    footer p {margin-top:40px; text-align:center; font-size:12px;}
24  22    footer .separator {opacity:0.3; margin:0 10px;}
25  23    @media (max-width: 979px) {footer .separator {display:block; visibility:hidden; width:1px; height:1px;}}
26  24    .pagination {margin:40px 0;}
27  25    .pagination p {float:left;}
28      - .alert {margin-top:15px;}
```

Here is my test site.
http://ec2-54-227-129-183.compute-1.amazonaws.com/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's cached in your browser, the version being served is your modified one. Try a full refresh or viewing in a private/incognito browser session to quickly check.

To help with upgrades you could create a custom CSS file in your site's app that overrides the Mezzanine defaults. You'll inherit Mezzanine's default styles as they change with newer versions:

(templates/base.html)

```
{% compress css %}
...
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/mezzanine.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/mysite.css">
...
{% block extra_css %}{% endblock %}
{% endcompress %}
```

Comment: I tried incognito mode. The same CSS is being served up in both places.

Comment: Have you done a ``python manage.py collectstatic``? This will copy any overrides in the static root.

Comment: I have not ran that locally (while in debug mode). I have also not run that on my server where I use fab deploy.